# Using GPS Module ET314AC With arduino Mega

Tags: arduino-mega, gps

Can I use GPS Module ET314AC with Arduino Mega? Here is the datasheet of ET314AC            [ET314AC Datasheet](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC0QFjADahUKEwil6qrq4vnIAhVBhRoKHQePBOM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.szstoton.com%2Fres%2Fstotongps%2Fpdres%2F201203%2F20120320163340251.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFOZ31eexhFJWxNYqHvN-QWt4GoEA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can, the datasheet is saying that you can read from a serial port which is what you want to do.

Connecting the serial port to TX and RX pins of the Arduino, ground and power, you should be able to talk to the module.

I cant find a breakboard for this module so I suppose you are going to solder it or you can give us the link where you bought it.

I suggest you to try with TinyGPS library to decode the data, after you are sure that the module is talking to the Arduino correctly.

Comment: Yes I'm going to solder it manually as I got it from a local store for $4. I also got an active antenna (this one : http://www.aliexpress.com/item/1575-42MHZ-Magnetic-base-GPS-active-Antenna-with-SMA-Plug-connector-for-GPS-receivers-and-Mobile/1531700595.html ) and I'll really appreciate your help if you can tell me how to connect this antenna with above mentioned gps module again I do not have any breakout module and I have to done it manually.

Comment: that is an active antenna so it means you need to connect more than one pin to the gps module. At page 11 you can see the small schematic to connect the antenna